# Find only top directories matching search

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, find

I'm trying to find all the web folders that are 777. But I only want a list of the top folders.

So if there is an img dir that has folders in it that are also 777 I don't want them returned.

Basically I'm looking for a way to have find stop descending after finding a folder that's 777.

```
find /var/www/vhosts/ -type d -perm 777
```

Gives me

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/img
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/img/gbl
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/img/ss
```

And all i want is the first one

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/img
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the -prune flag.

`find /var/wwwhosts/ -type -d -perm 777 -prune` should show exactly what you want.

Edit:  Here's what this is doing for me, I believe this is what you wanted?

```
# ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Feb 25 14:21 c

# ls -l c
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 25 14:21 1
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Feb 25 14:21 2

# find . -perm 777 -prune
./c

# find . -perm 777 -prune -exec ls -ld {} \;
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Feb 25 14:21 ./c
```

Comment: That will return everything except the 777 folders. Maybe I can find a way to prune if the parent is 777 ?

Comment: Really?  What OS/Bash version are you running on?  This works perfectly for me.  All the prune does is prevent recursing any further into the directory.  It still prints the output.

Comment: I just suck at reading! You win! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Completely understandable.  It's some pretty counter-intuitive behavior from prune.